# CF10 / IIS 7.5 handling of paths different on the same server

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have two websites on an IIS 7.5 box. I don't recall doing anything with the config on Site #1 that would make it special relative to #2, but I can't figure out a behavior in #2 that isn't there in #1.

With links in the site, #1 works "as expected", however #2 - unless I specific the sub folder path, reverts back to the site root. For example, in sub directories of site #1, I can just link to another page within that same directory like this:

```
<a href="otherpage.cfm">go to other page</a>
```

However, on site #2 I'm having to use the full path on any links in a sub directory or else they go back to the root level.

```
Structure:
    root/sub/anothersub/
    <a href="otherpage.cfm">go to other page</a>
```

This (to me anyway) should go to `www.site2.com/sub/anothersub/otherpage.cfm` but it's instead going to `www.site2.com/otherpage.cfm`.

I can get it to work if I change my links to either be full domain + path or path relative to root, but I'm curious what I could have changed so that site 2 isn't acting like site 1.

```
<a href="/sub/anothersub/otherpage.cfm">
or
<a href="http://www.site2.com/sub/anothersub/otherpage.cfm">
```

Both sites have static IPs and SSL.  SSL seems makes no difference (http vs. https, etc.).

Comment: Have your pages got the `<base>` tag specified in the head?  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: D'OH!!!!  So obvious yet I've been thinking it had to be the server config, and there it was in the header include.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're outputting a `<base>` tag in your pages, e.g.

```
<base href="http://www.site2.com/">
```

Find where that's happening, remove it, problem solved.